# logical error in do-while loop during implementation of data structure "stack"

Tags: c, loops

My teacher gave me a homework problem in which we have to `push` and `pop` elements in a stack.

The input shall be: -

> 1. First line of input must contain no. of elements in the stack.
> 2. Second line of input must contain the choice of user (i.e.) whether to PUSH (i.e. entering `'1'`) or POP element (i.e. entering
>      `'2'`).
> 3. If PUSH operation has been selected as user's choice; then third line of input must contain the element to be pushed into stack.
> 4. the next line of input must contain either `'y'` or `'n'` as a reply to if the user wishes to continue these operations.

**Test Case 1**

**INPUT**

> 3 `//(capacity of stack)`
>
> 1 `//(selecting PUSH OR POP)`
>
> 6 `//(entering the element which is to entered)`
>
> y `//(to continue or not continue)`
>
> 1 `//(selecting PUSH OR POP)`
>
> 4 `//(entering the element which is to entered)`
>
> y `//(to continue or not continue)`
>
> 1 `//(selecting PUSH OR POP)`
>
> 7 `//(entering the element which is to entered)`
>
> y `//(to continue or not continue)`
>
> 2 `//(selecting PUSH OR POP)`
>
> n `//(to continue or not continue)`

**OUTPUT**

> `deleted element is`
>
> `7 4 6`

For the above problem I have written the following code: -

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
};

void push(struct Stack *stack, int a) //function to PUSH a character in the stack.
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = a;
}

int pop(struct Stack *stack) //function to POP a character in the stack.
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Stack obj;
    obj.top = -1;

    printf("Enter the capacity of stack\n");
    scanf("%d", &obj.capacity); //Inputting the capacity of the stack.

    obj.array = calloc(obj.capacity, sizeof(int));

    int operation;
    int element;
    char continuation;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter 1 if you want to PUSH or 2 for POP\n");
        scanf("%d", &operation);

        printf("\nEnter the element which is to be pushed\n");
        scanf("%d", &element);

        scanf("%*c"); //To ignore any newline in stdin buffer.
        printf("\nEnter 'y' if you want to continue else enter 'n'\n");
        scanf("[a-z]%c", &continuation);

        if(operation == 1)
        {
            if(obj.top < obj.capacity)
            {
                push(&obj, element);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        else if(operation == 2)
        {
            printf("deleted element is\n");
            while(obj.top != -1) //will POP all elements on the stack and print it.
            {
                printf("%d", pop(&obj));
                if(obj.top != 0)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Wrong operation specified\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } while(continuation == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

The problem which I am encountering in the above code is that after entering the following input: -

> 3
>
> 1
>
> 6
>
> y

The programme closes (i.e. exiting `do-while` loop). Howsoever when I change the below line in the code: -

`char continuation;`

to

`char continuation = 'y';`

It is working fine until I input the following: -

> 3
>
> 1
>
> 6
>
> y
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> y
>
> 1
>
> 7
>
> y

which afterwards gives me an abrupt output of : -

> `Error`

and then exits the programme.

My question is : -

> Why my code does not work in the first case when i only write `char continuation;` ?
>
> What is the "logical error" in the second case when I change `char continuation;` to `char continuation = 'y';` ?

Comment: I think `"[a-z]%c"` wants to scan a literal "[a-z]", then a character. The format `" %c"` (with a leading space)  skips white-space including the newline and then tries to read a non-space character. I say "tries", because the scanning may fail, which the return value of `scanf` will tell you. In my opinion, interactive input like yours is best real line-wise with `fgets` for example, and then parsed. The `sscanf` fucntion takes its input from a string.

Comment: The error message seems links to the case operation == 1 and obj.top >= obj.capacity (your code). 
You should print the values scanned or use a debugger to see why you reach this branch.

Comment: @Nico238 but `obj.top` has to less than `obj.capacity`

Comment: @MOehm so my solution to eat a `\n` is totally wrong?

Comment: Yes. `scanf("%*c");` "eats" the next character after reading a decimal number. That character may or may not be a new-line character. If the input had been "6x", it would have been the `'x'`. I don't think there is a format to scan a single character from a set, but you could check with `isalpha` or `islower` from `<ctype.h>` until you get one. In any case, you should prepare for the possibility of misformatted or erroneous input.

Comment: Besides, try to avoid mixing (interleaving) like you did. After asking for operation to do, first perform the operation, *then* ask whether continue or not. So, errors related to operation are printed suddenly, not after having asked to continue or not.

Comment: @linuxfan I had to write the above code in such a way because I have to submit it in my college server AND the input stream is specified just like the way mentioned above. Even all the `printf` function which i have written has to be deleted; except outputting the desired output.

Comment: @Swarnim Khosla you enters 4 times in your loop. Add trace output to see what the values of your variables are : `printf("capa :  %d, top : %d, op : %d\", obj.capacity, obj.top, operation);`

Comment: @Nico238 I inserted your code in the last of my `do-while` loop and is now acting more weirdly. After one loop it is showing `capa : 3, top : 3, op : 1` and exiting the programming. I don't know why is `top : 3`.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla it is because your parsing of inputs is wrong. You read multiple times the sames values. Output the values you read until you find the good formatting (see @M Oehm comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem by removing`"[a-z]%c"` and replacing it with `" %c"`.

This is my new (correct) code.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int top;
    int *array;
};

void push(struct Stack *stack, int a) //function to PUSH a character in the stack.
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = a;
}

int pop(struct Stack *stack) //function to POP a character in the stack.
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Stack obj;
    obj.top = -1;

    printf("Enter the capacity of stack\n");
    scanf("%d", &obj.capacity); //Inputting the capacity of the stack.

    obj.array = calloc(obj.capacity, sizeof(int));

    int operation;
    int element;
    char continuation;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter 1 if you want to PUSH or 2 for POP\n");
        scanf("%d", &operation);

        if(operation == 1)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the element which is to be pushed\n");
            scanf("%d", &element);

            if(obj.top < obj.capacity)
            {
                push(&obj, element);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Error\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        else if(operation == 2)
        {
            printf("deleted element is\n");
            while(obj.top != -1) //will POP all elements on the stack and print it.
            {
                printf("%d", pop(&obj));
                if(obj.top != 0)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Wrong operation specified\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        scanf("%*c"); //To ignore any newline in stdin buffer.
        printf("\nEnter 'y' if you want to continue else enter 'n'\n");
        scanf(" %c", &continuation);

    } while(continuation == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Note: - I have also avoided interleaving `printf` as suggested in the comments.

Howsoever I am still not able to understand why my previous code didn't work.

**P.S.**

I finally got my mistake, instead of writing `"[a-z]%c"` it should be `"%[a-z]c"`.